# Rules for writing delete queries in JPQL

Tags: jpa, jpql, toplink

Are there any **rules** to write queries (especially delete) in JPQL with Toplink Persistence Provider? 
any reference please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean, like the JPA spec ? the thing that defines the (JPQL) query language. See the links at the foot of [this page](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_1/jpa/api.html).